# What is this structure in a park

Tags: civil-engineering, hydrology

It really has no informative signs on it just signs warning not climb or careful with your ball. It is in a Japanese park. I thought it is a water mound with its lots of pipes coming out it for aquifer to water the park. [image]

[image: Tightly stonework like a Japanese castle]

[image: Some barbed wire fenced off plants]

Comment: That is a retaining wall. The pipes are weep holes that allows water to come out so that it will not build into additional pressure. :)

Comment: It is a four sided structure- why?

Comment: I am not sure what structure lies above it based on your picture, but having some fences above it, it must be very important. How long do you think it is in both sides?

Comment: 10 metres by 5 metres- nothing important just plants- no easy access possible.

Comment: giving the name of the park might be useful. There could be some historical significance.  Not really an engineering question though.

Comment: Omiya Daini Koen which mean Omiya's second park - if it is historical why no nameplate.

Comment: the park has a wikipedia page (no mention of the feature),  You might ask for info on the talk page.

Answer (score 1):

As Jem Eripol points out, it is to prevent erosion / collapse of the earth above it.  Likely the land was cleared and leveled to produce the park, and to prevent the hillside above it from filling in the space, the retaining wall was added.  There is also the element of the designer thinking it "looked cool" -- that is a function in and of itself.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is a contained area/ building- why not just remove the soil. It look hideous. Who would want a built inaccessible area in a park.